# Return references from a swift ternary operator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
let myRef = isTrue() ? &objectA : &objectB
```

errors: "Use of extraneous '&'"

This can be done within a classic if/else conditional, but not in a ternary. Does anyone know why?

Comment: I don’t know the answer, but do note that any form of `let myRef = &objectA` is already a really bad idea. The surprise is that it is permitted in the first place.

Comment: @matt Why is it a bad idea? I have 6 similar network requests that update unique structs. I'm passing the struct as a reference to the abstracted network request so they can be modified

Comment: It really depends on context: it could be that you don't need a pointer at all (common for example when you are trying to do direct port of some code to Swift; instead it could be a different function signature all together). Or it could be that you need to actually construct something like UnsafePointer (e.g. `let myRef = isTrue() ? UnsafePointer(&objectA) : UnsafePointer(&objectB)`). And there are many other options. So what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @KirilS. I have a function which updates a struct. This struct is passed as an `inout myStruct` parameter. The ternary operator is to determine which struct to pass to the function

Comment: Passing an address as an inout argument to a function is not at all the same as assigning it to a constant.

Comment: Can you show the method this code is in? What are the types of `objectA` and `objectB`?

Comment: shouldn't the classic if/else still yields the same error. @matt is right in that just call the func passing the inout in each of the condition instead of assigning it to an extra property if the purpose is just to update the struct. :)

Comment: in Xcode 11.4, `let myRef = &objectA` will not compile at all, and rightly so

Answer (score 1):

> I have a function which updates a struct. This struct is passed as an inout myStruct parameter. The ternary operator is to determine which struct to pass to the function

Ah. It would have been helpful to say that in the original question.

You can't use `&` like that because an "address" in Swift isn't really a thing. If you don't want to get into unsafe pointers, and if the goal is to call a function `f` with inout argument `&objectA` or `&objectB` depending on a condition, make the call *itself* conditional:

```
isTrue() ? f(&objectA) : f(&objectB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign an object to `myRef` (and it must be a `var`!), then take reference on function call:

```
// Given
struct Test {
    var x: String
}

func isTrue() -> Bool {
    return Bool.random()
}

func byRef(test: inout Test) {

    test.x = String(test.x.reversed())
}

let objectA = Test(x: "hello")
let objectB = Test(x: "hola")

// Now create a ref
// Note that it MUST be a var (not let)
var myRef = isTrue() ? objectA : objectB

// Now we can pass it to a function
print("Before: \(myRef.x)")
byRef(test: &myRef)
print("After: \(myRef.x)")
```